# Why we apply delay between retry requests

Tags: java, design-patterns, retrypolicy, exponential-backoff

When we have a piece of code that often fails and must be retried. Then we use retry pattern.

```
try {
        //do request here
} catch (Exception e) {
        //wait for some millisecond and retry
        retry();
}
```

We normally delay for some millisecond before retry that request. I want to know that why we need some delay? What will happen if retry request did not wait and send request again.

Comment: What can happen is that you hammer the server with requests and potentially make the problem worse

Comment: It is unlikely that a problem with the server is fixed in a few microseconds so an immediate retry is very unlikely to work and as JonK said would only contribute to problem.

Comment: So that we don't make the original problem even worse.

Comment: Ooo I see. Many thanks for adding this concept in my knowledge.

Comment: Before you hand-build lots of stuff like this, also check out libraries that have many ready-made primitives for retries and other resilience, eg https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe [no personal involvement with this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the benefit of using exponential backoff?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732327/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-exponential-backoff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that a problem with the server is fixed in a few microseconds so an immediate retry is very unlikely to work and would only contribute to problem. So a delay between retry is best practice to follow.